# How to get values from one column where another column's values match a list

Tags: python, pandas

We have a dataframe:

```
      column1  column2
0        A       h
1        B       l
2        C       p
```

and a list:

```
li = ['p', 'l']
```

How can I use the list to look up values in `column2` and return the corresponding `column1` values in that order?

The desired result:

```
np.array(['C', 'B'])
```

I tried this, but it does not preserve the order:

```
df.loc[df['column2'].isin(li)]['column1'].values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like -

```
df_new = df[df['column2'].isin(li)]
df_new.index = [li.index(x) for x in df_new['column2']]
df_new = df_new.sort_index()
df_new['column1'].values
# array(['C', 'B'], dtype=object)
```

If you are using version 1.x of `pandas` - you can think of using the `key` argument that comes with the `sort_values` function like [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Answer (score 4):

Set `column2` as the index and use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.set_index('column2').loc[li, 'column1'].values

# array(['C', 'B'], dtype=object)
```